# Find a specific value in a database php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have tried different methods and none of them seem to work. When I try the command in the MySQL console it works fine, but when I try it in this PHP script it sends me back an empty string.

```
$search = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT item_path FROM items WHERE item_title = ?");

while (array_key_exists($i, $parts)) {
    // An array that contains (word1, word2, word3)
    $data = $parts[$i];

    // Wraps data in "" for mysqli query
    $data = "\"" . $data . "\"";

    // Binding here still doesn't work
    $search->bind_param("s", $data);

    // This should execute the above prepare and give me the data
    // from the way I think it work's this execute() should use the updated $data
    $search->execute();
    $search->bind_result($img_path);
    $search->fetch();

    // This returns an empty string
    echo $img_path;
    echo "<img src= \"", $img_path, "\" >";

    $i++;
}
```

If I go into the MySQL console and run:

```
SELECT item_path FROM items WHERE item_title = "word1"
```

I get the item_path I am expecting but for some reason it my script it returns an empty string.

Thanks in advance for helping (if you do)!

EDIT:

```
    // Wraps data in "" for mysqli query
    $data2 = "\"" . $data . "\"";

    // Binding here still doesn't work even after changing the var
    $search->bind_param("s", $data2);
```

I tired to change the bind to another variable, but still I get an empty string. I'm not sure if it's cause I'm wraping the data incorrectly or if there is another reason. I have been searching for something else like this to happen and I have came up with nothing.

Comment: You could try setting $img_path to a default value before you do the query. That would tell you whether the bind is failing, or whether it's succeeding and writing a blank string.

Comment: Ah a great idea, I just tried that and yes it is returning a empty string. Which makes me think I'm querying it wrong, but I'm not sure how to quote an item correctly. I'm pretty sure I'm doing it the wrong way.

Comment: Try running it without wrapping the data in quotes. Quoting should not be necessary for prepared queries. In fact, I think adding quotes to the string will cause SQL to search for strings that have quote marks in them, which is probably why your query is failing.

Comment: Oh I was pretty sure that was the first thing I tried but messing around with that and getting rid of the "" part and I got it to work, that you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind your statement outside of the clause, and you never use the `$data` that you changed.

```
$search = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT item_path FROM items WHERE item_title = ?");

while (array_key_exists($i, $parts)) {
    // An array that contains (word1, word2, word3)
    $data = $parts[$i];

    // Wraps data in "" for mysqli query
    $data = "\"" . $data . "\"";

    // Bind it here instead!
    $search->bind_param("s", $data);

    // This should execute the above prepare and give me the data
    $search->execute();
    $search->bind_result($img_path);
    $search->fetch();

    // This returns an empty string
    echo $img_path;
    echo "<img src= \"", $img_path, "\" >";

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I have tried binding it inside of the While Loop and it still doesn't work. I also use $search->execute(); which should use the changed $data.

Comment: Taking yours and octern's suggestion and it worked, so thanks.